# Loggin a una website desde mi programa

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion de consola en C# basica. La idea es que loggee a un sitio (el cual ya tengo los headers necesarios), ya almacene en variables los datos ingresados por la persona.
¿Hay alguna manera "sencilla" de lograr esto? Estuve viendo GET/POST pero realmente no entendi.

La idea seria la siguiente:

- Pedir al usuario su usuario/contraseña (Ok)
- Almacenar esos datos en variables (Ok)
- Con esos datos llenar un formulario de login en una pagina
- Una vez logrado el login imprimir en consola el texto que hay dentro de un ID en el HTML (que tambien lo tengo)

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que intentas es hacer un programa C# para hacer login en una página ¿cierto?

Deberías hacer un HttpPost (no GET) a la URL en la que la Web recupere las credenciales.

Es decir, hacer un POST sobre la URL que figure en el action del formulario de la pantalla de login.

En este otro hilo, creo que comentan tu mismo problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930807/c-sharp-login-to-website-via-program

Comment: Esa la probé pero por algún motivo no pasó nada. Creo que era porque Webresponse no estaba definido